# Rename the 'makefile' build.exe expects to something that won't clash?

Tags: nmake, wdk

In the DDK/WDK the `build.exe` expects certain files in a folder. As soon as you give a `sources` file, you are also expected to have a `makefile` in the same folder. Obviously this name clashes with all kinds of `make` variants in a mixed source tree that is built on various platforms and tool chains.

Is there a way to name it something else, such as `makefile.ddk` and have `nmake.exe` (the backend to `build.exe` for this step) pick up on that other name?

I'm not afraid to script things, but I would prefer if I could pass an option to `build.exe`, e.g. via the `/nmake args` switch. I am using a range of DDKs/WDKs from the 2003 Server IFS Kit to the latest Windows 7 and 8 WDKs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The /nmake option will do the job.  I just tested this and it works:

```
build /nmake "/f makefile.ddk"
```

The quotes are necessary.

Comment: Aah, brilliant. That explains why I couldn't get it to work (the quotes). Thanks so much.